# DotNetchk in DotNetFX Bootstrapper

Tags: .net, package

I'm looking for some documentation on DotNetchk (what it checks for, how it works, command line params, and exit codes) which is part of the DotNetFX Bootstrapper package.

Edit 1: There is a relevant msdn [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/7c0c708c-6bf4-4d22-aa42-3724622bfa53) and a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2006/02/06/using-dotnetchk.aspx), but I'm looking for a more complete overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a classic XY question.  Surely the X question is "how do I check if .NET is installed myself?"  By checking the registry, well covered in other questions at SO.

If you really want to know what dotnetchk.exe does (not documented) then it is easy enough to reverse-engineer.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility, have tracing turned on while you run dotnetchk.  You'll see all the registry keys and files it looks at in the trace.

Comment: I'm looking for some official msdn documentation. It would seem that the checker for the .net bootstrapper package should be documented. I'd hate to have to disassemble it myself...Thank's for the Process monitor link.

Comment: You are asking for a pony, there are no such docs.  Only what it returns is documented.  I'd recommend you actually use it.

Comment: Well then I'm going to have to do some of my own checks afterwords then...thanks anyways.